# Deploying a web application project made using DashCode on iphone

Tags: iphone, dashcode

I have developed a web application project using Dashcode for iPhone.

It is running fine on iPhone simulator. Can anyone help  me to deploy it on a iphone and test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webapp is basically an app that is HTML CSS and JS based and totally runs on a web browser of a mobile device.

I am calling the URL of my app from the safari browser and thus able to see it.